# Trying to make discord.py bot say something when its gets mentioned, doesnt respond

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When someone mentions the bot, I want it to respond saying, "Hey! I've been mentioned. My prefix is `>`. You can type `>help` to see my commands." I have the code written out but the bot does not respond at all when it gets mentioned. I do not get any errors when I run it or mention the bot. How do I get this to work? My code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
       return
  msg_content = message.content.lower()

  mention = ['@830599839623675925', '@Ultimate Bot']
 
  if any(word in msg_content for word in mention):
    await message.channel.send("Hey! I've been mentioned. My prefix is `>`. You can type `>help` to see my commands.")
  else:
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`mentioned_in()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mentioned_in) method.

So in this case it would be;

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id == bot.user.id: return
 
  if bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
    await message.channel.send("Hey! I've been mentioned.")
  
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Some things to note:

- Hard-coding in values such as in your `mention` variable is bad practice. It makes it much harder to maintain your code, and when your project gets bigger you may question what the purpose of these seemingly random strings are referring to. For example, if you were to change the name of the bot, or to transfer your code to a new bot, going through your entire codebase and picking out and changing these values would be far from ideal.
- I don't know about the rest of your application, but you probably don't want `process_commands()` to be in the `else` statement. For example, if the user mentions the bot in their message, but are using a command, the command will be blocked because you are not triggering `process_commands()`.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

You could instead just check if bot.user is in the message mentions.

You can also check if the bot display name was used.

```py
if bot.user in message.mentions or (message.guild and message.guild.me in message.mentions):
    print("bot was mentioned")
elif message.guild and message.guild.me.display_name in message.content:
    print("bot name was used")
```